# JAVA web application Asynchronous push notification to let user know status of long running job

Tags: java

I have a spring mvc/struts, hibernate application. We ran into a problem where in we are executing a long running on one of application page. We would like to execute this process in background however we want to show status of the process to end client when process gets completed. The condition is user can navigate to a different page and even on different page he/she should be notified with a dialog box or so for a long running process which was initiated bye him/her.

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks in advance
Anant

Answer (score 0):

Execute the task in a thread, and either poll with ajax through an iframe, or push updates to the client using websockets

Comment: Can you please refer me some link or blog where I can see sample implementation

Comment: sorry, you are going to have to try something first, I gave you the basics